# Please Explain spring MVC , hibernate and Spring security

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I just managed to create my first login page using Spring security and hibernate, with the help of a lot of guides.

The problem I faced was mostly that the guides didn't have very thorough explanations, so I was hoping that I could get some answers through you guys.

Question 1:
Why do we create the interface class for e.g UserDao? I know the purpose of this interface is to gain access to a database of some sort. But since my UserDao only contains:

```
public interface UserDao {

User findByUserName(String userName);

boolean insertUser(User user);

}
```

Can't I just create a class instead?

Question 2:

What Actually happens behind the scenes when I run:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {  
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}
```

Question 3:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws  
UsernameNotFoundException {
code...
}
    }
```

When and how does this class get called?

I have read the most of docs and still do not understand.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you study the documentation? Your question is too broad for this site as a comprehensive answer would be too long and just duplicate the documentation.

Comment: Yes, as stated I've read the docs and did not manage to comprehend what was written, also I'm pretty sure the first two questions are not that broad. I'm not really asking for a duplicate, what I'm asking for is an explanation from a different perspective.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for Q1**

**Programming without DAO interfaces.**

- Let's say you are a programmer in a huge system who is responsible to add components according to new requirement.
- From the begining your system is implemented to work with MySQL.
- Due to a new requirement your project manager asked you to implement support for Oracle. (Whenever needed DB support should be switched between MySQL and Oracle)
- MySQL queries and Oracle queries are different.
- Your system is not implemented with an ORM framework like hibernate.
- Specially, there are no DAO interfaces. All are concrete classes to communicate with DB.
- Now you are going to implement java classes with methods including queries related to Oracle.
- You are in a trouble,
- Your system is huge
- It is included complex business logics
- Without examining service layer code or documentations you are unable to
- know (You cannot change the service layer code.)
- what classes/methods should I implement with which names.
- What should be methods' input parameters.
- What should be output.
- Surely it will take months depending on the system complexity. (Time reduction is a key point in software projects)

**But with DAO interfaces**

- You need only to think about the Oracle specific queries because
- You just implements the DAO interfaces
- Automatically dao interfaces keep you on the track
- to use correct method names
- to use correct input parameters
- to use correct return variables
- If you out of the track, compilation will be failed.
- And you can easily plug the oracle or mysql support with bean injection